# Nesting IF and OR statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having troubles getting Excel to calculate a formula using IF and OR.

I have a spreadsheet where I need the information from K6*I6 to be nested.  I need it to differentiate the percentage that's listed in cell K (it will be either `12.5%` or `25%`) and then calculate based on that. For instance - if K=25% and K6*I6<=150 I need it to put in `150` BUT if it's more than `75` I need it to put the total amount BUT if K=`12.5%` and K6*I6<=75 I need it to put in `75`.

I can't seem to get the right syntax for it to work.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: It seems to me that the first comparison should be `>=150`, and not `<=150`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=MAX(600*K6,I6*K6)
```

Work out:

600*K6 (Will either be 75 or 150 depending on if K is 12.5% or 25%)

K6*I6

Take the maximum value